# Union of two elements in a sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, simple-functions

Let $f$ and $g$ are two non-negetive simple functions on $X$. Then show that  the set $A$ belongs to $£$, where $A=\{x:f(x)>=g(x)\}$ and $£$ is the sigma algebra of subsets of $X$.

Also I stuck with a problem in my mind that can we say the sets $\{x∈X:f(x)>g(x)\}$ and $\{x∈X:f(x)=g(x)\}$ are also elements of $£$?
I think no, as if $AUB∈£$ we can not say that both belongs to $£$. Please help me for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show that if $f$ and $g$ are measurable then $h = f-g$ is also measurable.

> **Lemma.** If $f,g$ are measurable then $f+g$ is measurable.
>   **Proof.** For
>   any $a\in \mathbb{R}$ then $$  (f+g)^{-1}(-\infty, a) = \{x: f(x) +
> g(x) > a\} = \bigcup_{r\in \mathbb{Q}} \{x: f(x)> a - r\} \cup \{x:
> g(x)>r\}$$ which is measurable.

Then the problem is reduced to showing $\{x: h(x) \geq 0\}$ is measurable, as it can be written as
$$ \{x: h(x) \geq 0\} = \{x: h(x)<0\}^c$$
and the latter is
$$\{x: h(x)<0\} = \bigcup_{n\geq 1} \left\lbrace x: h(x) < -\frac{1}{n}\right\rbrace$$
Note that each set $\left\lbrace x: h(x) < -\frac{1}{n}\right\rbrace$ is $h^{-1}\left( -\infty, -\frac{1}{n}\right)$ which is measurable if $h$ is measurable.

The same also hold true for other sets like $\{x: h(x) = 0\}$ or $\{x: g(x)>0\}$ by the same way of re-writing subsets.